# "Articles for you" suggestion on Chrome Desktop (Chrome Content Suggestions)

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome mobile shows "Articles for you" formally known as "Chrome Content Suggestions" on the new tab page `chrome://newtab` (screenshot below).

I would really like to have these suggestions also on my desktop New Tab Page (NTP), I know they are loathed, but I actually find them very useful (look at those suggestions in the screenshot!).

My hope was that using the Developer Tools > Useragent spoofer to set the useragent to `Pixel 2XL` would be sufficient, but it does not appear to be the case (I have tested this on Linux and on Windows desktops).

The "snippets" appear to be downloaded (on mobile) using [fetch.py](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/ntp_snippets/remote/fetch.py), tried running this but it gives the following error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../../google_apis/internal/google_chrome_api_keys.h'
```

Which indeed does not exist (the `internal` directory doesn't in fact).

Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Chrome Content Suggestions]

[image: Linux Chromium newtab with useragent Pixel 2XL]

[image: Windows Chrome newtab with useragent Pixel 2XL]

[image]

Comment: @Bastian Did you find any solution to your question? I am looking for a way to retrieve these article suggestions programatically (either on desktop or mobile chrome) and it's a total hassle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I did not unfortunately. The behaviour has also become more complicated since then, it used to just be a webpage, where you could e.g. "open in new tab". The new "Discovery" feature  on new tab doesn't work like that anymore. (and it lists far fewer suggestions for me :-( )

Answer (score 5):

I love this feature on my ipad.  If you make this https://news.google.com/foryou your homepage on Desktop Chrome I believe you get the same results.

Comment: These two services aren't showing the same results. News only shows data from a curated list of sources. Chrome's recommendations can show recommendations from any website.

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://news.google.com and select "For you" from left side panel. You need to already login to Chrome with Google ID.

Comment: https://news.google.com/foryou is a direct link to suggestion. Languages mixed on the mobile chrome home, you need to choose one locale on this desktop page.

Comment: there are completely different recommendations.